# При изменении текста label на jquery получаю ошибку

Tags: javascript, jquery

На страничке имеется label:

```
<label id="price-label" class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="price">Price</label>
```

При попытке изменить текст с помощью jquery:

```
let price = $('#price-label').text();
price.text('Cost');
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: price.text is not a function

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша переменная `price` - строка.

---

```
$('#price-label').text('Cost');
```

или

```
let price = $('#price-label');
let oldPriceText = price.text();
price.text('Cost');
```

```js
function changePriceToCost() {
  let price = $('#price-label');
  let oldPriceText = price.text();
  price.text('Cost');
  console.log(oldPriceText, "->", price.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="price-label" class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="price">Price</label>

<br/>
<button onclick="changePriceToCost()">Change Price to Cost</button>
```

Comment: Теперь ошибку не получаю, но текст в label не меняется)

Comment: @ArtemNikolaevich У меня - меняется.

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо.